# Why is the value in input not load with a value from vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to make the **value** entered in **input** saved into **vuex** and then in **vuex** store saved in **localstorage**, and then if the application was closed, when reopened, the value saved in localstorage should be returned to input. Now for some reason my input value is not saved. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or, if possible, correct the code. Thank!

**Сomponent**

```
<f7-list-input
  placeholder="Username"
  type="text"
  v-bind:value="name"
  @input="onPersist"
/>

export default {
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    this.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
        }
    },

computed:{
    name(){
        return this.$store.state.name;
    }
},
methods:{
    onPersist(){
        this.$store.commit('persist',event.target.value);
    }
}
    };
    </script>
```

**VUEX store**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        name: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        persist(state,payload){
        state.name = payload; 
        localStorage.setItem('name', state.name);
       },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set up the value of a computed property which do not have any setter for it. Now, without any set method declared for your computed property, this line of your code

```
this.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
```

won't cause any reactive change or mutate the state in the vuex store. You should read more about [form handling in vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) to get a better understanding for it.

To solve your problem, you just need to commit the *'persist'* mutation in your mounted hook with the fetched data from the local storage.

```
<f7-list-input
placeholder="Username"
type="text"
:value="name"
@input="onPersist"/>

export default {
 mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    // 'name' is a computed property without a setter
    // hence, below line in your code doesn't reflect change
    //
    // this.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    //
    // instead you should commit the value to the store
    // and let vuex take care of everything

    const existingName = localStorage.getItem('name');
    this.$store.commit('persist', existingName);
  }
 },

 computed:{
   name(){
    return this.$store.state.name;
   }
 },

 methods:{
  onPersist(){
    this.$store.commit('persist',event.target.value);
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this? I can’t figure out how to transfer a value from input to a block before saving it in localstorage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799648/why-the-value-from-input-is-not-passed-to-vuex